# Flutter run timer in Workmanager

Tags: flutter

I would like to implement a function in my Flutter app to run an audio recorder in background so that even if I move my app to background, the audio recording still runs.

Before actually working on audio recording, I plan to test the `Workmanager` library with a timer. However, the timer does not work properly. I would like to get some advice on it. Can I please get some advice on how to get it working?

As a trigger, I have a button to start the background work

```
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Workmanager().initialize(runner,
                               isInDebugMode: true
                               );
      Workmanager().registerOneOffTask("task-identifier", "simpleTask", tag: 'simpleTask');
      },
    child: const Text('Start')),
```

And I have an entry level function to run the timer

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void runner() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    print('hello');
    try {
      var timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        print(DateTime.now());
      });
    } catch (err) {
      Logger().e(err.toString()); // Logger flutter package, prints error on the debug console
      throw Exception(err);
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Here is the log showing some info

```
I/flutter (27585): hello
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(27585): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=e2614099-8787-4f93-abe1-7ee456dd3a0d, tags={ be.tramckrijte.workmanager.BackgroundWorker, simpleTask } ]
```

I find that the `print(DateTime.now());` statement is not called and nothing is printed.